# vba sheet name in array but show nothing

Tags: excel, vba

i want to show sheet name that match the word starting with "x" or "3" in array like this, but now only show the last one.

WshtNames = Array("X310361", "X310377", "X310379", "X310400", "310531", "310539", "X310561", "X310579", "X310605", "310610", "310645", "310646", "310647", "310653", "X310660", "X310662", "310665")

```
Sub MultiSheetArray()
'allows you to store an array of sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shtArray() As String
Dim intA As Integer
Dim intB As Integer
' First you need to enter the sheet names into an array
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If LCase(Left(ws.Name, 1)) = "x" Or Left(ws.Name, 1) = "3" Then
        intA = intA + 1
        ReDim Preserve shtArray(intA)
        shtArray(intA) = ws.Name
    End If
Next ws
' Now list the sheets we entered into our array "shtArray"

    Debug.Print shtArray(intA)

End Sub
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fhc3.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intA` is the last index in `shtArray()`.  `Debug.Print shtArray(intA)` will print the value in the last index.  `Join(shtArray,vbNewLine)` will join all the elements n in the array into a string separated by a line retur.

> ```
> Debug.Print Join(shtArray,vbNewLine)
> ```

The counter should be incremented after the array is resized and the value is added because the array starts at 0.  Otherwise, the first element in the array will not be given a value.

```
    If LCase(Left(ws.Name, 1)) = "x" Or Left(ws.Name, 1) = "3" Then
        ReDim Preserve shtArray(intA)
        shtArray(intA) = ws.Name
        intA = intA + 1
    End If
```

Comment: it's work but not my purpose. i got an error as below when i put this array into another for loop.



        WshtNames = Join(shtArray)
    For Each WshtNameCrnt In WshtNames

Comment: @kit38912739 I updated my answer.  Note: change `Debug.Print shtArray(intA)` to `Debug.Print shtArray(intA - 1) ` or better yet `Debug.Print shtArray(Ubound(shtArray))`

Comment: I caught the issue by running the code and checking the `shtArray` in the Locals Windows.  Watch:[Learn Excel - Video 291- VBA Interview - Watch-local-immediate Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-C7WpP82Ek)